# Caching WebView - Android, PhoneGap

Tags: android, caching, cordova, webview

I have read almost all the posts relating this topic - but nowhere i could find complete code how to implement cache in WebView Android ..

See I am supposed to make a project for caching multiple WebView pages along with images and data using PhoneGap preferably; have written a code in Java class file using Android specific but still I'm not able to execute fully as AVD gets disconnected when I switch to airplane mode... so my "else" part of the code (which is loading file from `/data/data/my.app/cache` to Android WebView) in Java class doesn't run too.

1. Could you suggest if I should implement caching (remember its
   WebView caching & not browser caching so m guessing cache-manifest
   option wont work) using Android specific or using Phonegap and why
2. Could you give me sample code for both of these implementations?
3. How to prevent AVD getting disconnected when flight mode is on